# Implementing Complex Motion and Choreography in Android Animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I'm currently exploring advanced animation techniques in Android development and seeking insights into implementing complex motion and choreography within my app. Specifically, I'm encountering challenges and seeking guidance on several key aspects:

For example, I want when click on every item of list open new scene. But I have an image in every item and I want show it in my new scene. So I need define animation between two images.

Thank you for sharing your expertise and experiences!